# Configure App Settings for Production and Staging slots via Bicep

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, staging, slot, azure-deployment-slots

I have a few Config App Settings in my function app as follows:

```
  {
    name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
    value: 1
  }
  {
    name: 'WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE'
    value: 1
  }
  {
    name: 'SCM_TOUCH_WEBCONFIG_AFTER_DEPLOYMENT'
    value: '0'
  }
  {
    name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
    value: 'dotnet'
  }
  {
    name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
    value: '~3'
  }
  {
    name: 'schedule'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'logAnalyticsId'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'logAnalyticsKey'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'storageAccountName'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'blobContainerName'
    value: ''
  }
  {
    name: 'appConfigurationEndpoint'
    value: ''
  }
```

I'm trying to add a new staging slot to my function app. I need all these settings same for both slots. Meaning, if I select swap, values from staging slot should be copied to productiom slot and vice versa. Should I set slotSetting to true or false?

Comment: You can set the `"slotSetting": true` property. if true the app setting won't be swap. more information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped

Comment: @Thomas Where in that article does it show the usage of that setting and how it can be used?